# How do I keep players from accessing certain commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I keep players from accessing certain commands?
I'm making a server and these kind of things are thing i need to know

Comment: I think we had a similar question before, but I can't find it. Maybe somebody who is more familiar with the minecraft tag can locate it.

Comment: What commands are you wanting to restrict access to? Players that are not OP'd cannot do a whole lot with commands, unless you have plugins installed.

Comment: In survival mode, almost all commands are disabled, with the exclusion of /help, /trigger, /me, /msg, and /say

Comment: Maybe someone can suggest a better title and the OP would be kind enough to edit it? I came here based off matching the answers and found it useful.

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13507/4797) - especially the part about "what you've tried so far."

Answer (score 6):

By default, the majority of commands (with the exception of `/me`, `/tell`, `/help`, and `/trigger` for some reason) are restricted to server ops. Players are, by default, not allowed to use any other commands on a server. Server ops can use other commands. You can specify ops in the `ops.txt` file, or by using the command `/op <playername>` in the console, or in-game (assuming you have added yourself as an op).

By default, server ops have access to all commands, including commands like `/stop`. You can change this by modifying the `op-permission-level` in your `server.properties` file. Setting it to 4 (which is the default) allows ops to use all commands. Setting it to 3 restricts the `/stop` command, setting it to 2 restricts server moderation commands (`/kick`, `/ban`, `/op`, `/deop`), and setting it to 1 removes all special permissions from ops other than the ability to bypass spawn protection. You can still use all of these commands in the server console.

Comment: thank you for the complete, accurate and thoughtful answer. I didn't ask the question, but I didn't know all the information you provided. It is very helpful.

Comment: What does `op-permission-level` 1 and zero do?

Comment: @NeilG op-permission-level 1 restricts all commands, and only gives ops the power to bypass spawn protection

Comment: so like "/op (player) gamemode"?

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to @Unionhawk's answer you could aternatively just use a permissions plugin such as [Group Manager](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Downloads) or [PermissionsEX](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permissionsex/) with Bukkit along with the [Essentials plugins](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/). I'd definitely recommend reading some guides on running a Minecraft server, [this not the best guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-Successful-Minecraft-Server) but a guide nonetheless and should point you in the right direction. Just google around to try find a guide that will suit you best in your objective.

Answer (score -4):

there are 3 steps-
1. In order for players to be able to break blocks near spawn, (spawn protection) they must be OP. So OP them.
2. close the server, and open the server.properties file   .
3. change the OP permission level to 1. this will restrict all OPs, so they no longer have commands. But, they can still break blocks around spawn.
    If you want to run commands, you must run them out of the server console.